# Javascript: getting smallest image within an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In my Cordova app I have an element with two images in it. Before the user clicks on a specific multipage tab, I don't know the Id of neither the container element or the images.

Once the user clicks on the multipage tab, the Id of the container element is passed to my function. This Id is called 'templateId'.

```
$(templateId).children("img").each(function() {
    alert('test');
    if($(this).width()<140) {
        $(this).addClass('smallImage');
    }
});

$('.smallImage').attr('src', $('#Screen01-myImage01').attr('src'));
```

The problem here is, the alert never fires. Also there are no errors in console.

I guess I'm doing this the wrong way. How do I get the smallest image from my element and use it to replace the src from #Screen01-myImage01 ?

Comment: Does the variable "templateId" actually contain a "#" (id) or "." (class)? Are you running your JavaScript after the DOM's ready?

Comment: the variable templateId contains 2 images with #id's, but no classes. I run it after the DOM's ready.

Comment: In your browsers developer tools set a breakpoint on `$(templateId).children("img")` and then paste `$(templateId).children("img")` in the console and see what comes back. If the alert is not fired your selector is most likely not what you think it is. My guess is your console will come back with something like `undefined` or `[]`

Comment: See [this bin](http://jsbin.com/ENUQoZUr/1/edit?html,js,output) for a working example. Compare it with yours.

Comment: how is this even possible @Kris Hollenbeck, it comes up as undefined.. but I have an alert that shows this id without problem..

Comment: Where is the alert that shows the id at? Is it defined before or after this function? And is it in the same scope?